# how can I install ubuntu desktop on a HTC HD2?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, htc

I am interested in exploring all the possibilities Ubuntu desktop mobile offers. I have an HTC HD2 and I am willing to experiment.

1. How can I install it on this device
2. Do I really need a cradle or another port (eg USB) can be used?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Ubuntu  from [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10116069&postcount=1)
2. Extract the archive.
3. Connect your device, and copy the "linux" folder to the root of your storage card, eg \Storage Card\linux
4. Disconnect your device, and run \Storage Card\linux\haret-pre-0.5.3-20100629_092009-QSD8250-ONLY.exe
5. Wait patiently. If the process takes more than 15 minutes, pull the battery and try again.

More information please click here : [Of course credit too](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10116069&postcount=1)